# Symfony 1.4 migration throws SQLSTATE [HY000]: General error: 1005 (err 150) - doctrine:migrate fails!

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine, migration

Here is a situation i could not resolve by myself.

I have an existing symfony 1.4 project with database, model and etc. I want to make a migration so I've done:

```
./symfony cc
./symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-db
./symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-model
```

All classes for the migration were created, so I've tried to apply the migration by:

```
./symfony doctrine:drop-db
./symfony doctrine:build-db
./symfony doctrine migrate
```

And the migration proccess crashes. It thros an error:

```
- SQLSTATE[1005]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'database.#sql-6df_301' (errno: 150). Failing Query: "ALTER TABLE product ADD CONSTRAINT "product_product_group_id_product_group_id FOREIGN KEY (product_group_id) REFERENCES product_group(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

This is strange. I have more tables with relations and they are created, but that one fails. I've check everything i can think of. The indexes types, the table types, the phase of the moon - everything seems to be OK. I've try to SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHEKS=0 to chase some ghosts, but NADA!

The error still occures.

Does anybody knows what is happening or a kind of solution?

Any suggestion?

Comment: I've cracked it up, but it seems my reputation is too low for STACKOVERFLOW to let me answering my question so early. After a 5 hours I'll post the answer. Clue: miss-ordered migration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've cracked it up.**

In a some hilarious reason the auto-generated migration classes are named like this:

```
1311678541_add<table-name>.php
1311678542_add<table-name>.php
1311678543_add<table-name>.php
...
13116785578_addfks.php
...
1311678579_add<table-name>.php
1311678580_add<table-name>.php
1311678582_addproductgroup.php
```

The `13116785578_addfks.php` file appears before `1311678582_addproductgroup.php`.

The file `13116785578_addfks.php` containing a class which creates all relations (foreign keys and constraints), but it tries to add constraint on a non existing table (in my case `product_group`, which will be created last). So, the SQL error means `YOU ARE TRYING TO CREATE A RELATION WITH UNEXISTING TABLE, YOU MORON!` :)

My soltion is to rename the `13116785578_addfks.php` to `13116785590_addfks.php` as it forces the doctrine merge machine to execute it as a last step. When executed all tables are already made and MySQL server is happy!

**So, what about the reason for this miss-ordering?**

Probably it caused by mixi'n up the to tasks `doctrine:generate-migrations-db` and `doctrine:generate-migrations-models`,
but the Symfony's Migration tutorial isn't very clear with this.

**Why I use them both?**

When I done `./symfony doctrine:generate-migration-db` only the half of classes for the migration was created. It is strange - there are only general tables and no related ones! So I called `doctrine:generate-migrations-models`.

**Conclusion**

Another question raises: Why `doctrine:generate-migrations-db` does not generate migration classes for related tables of the model?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use :generate-migrations-models . Try it with the sequence

```
./symfony cc
./symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-db
./symfony doctrine:drop-db
./symfony doctrine:build-db
./symfony doctrine migrate
```

The line

```
./symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-models
```

uses the model classes to generate the migrations. It's not always a good idea, because you could have forgotten models messing things up. In order to clean those forgotten models use the following before you start those commands above.

```
./symfony doctrine:clean-model-files
```

Comment: Yeah, i figured it out. The mixing with these two tasks was the problem. The auto-generated files for the migration was miss-ordered and FK creation was preformed before all the tables were created. Thank you.